# Case expression in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get all records (6 rows) from `testTable` if `a = 4`. `4` is default parameter in SP.

```
create table testTable(a int, b int, c int)
go
insert into testTable values(2, 101, 100000)
go
insert into testTable values(2, 101, 100001)
go
insert into testTable values(3, 101, 100002)
go
insert into testTable values(3, 102, 100003)
go
insert into testTable values(4, 1, 100004)
go
insert into testTable values(4, 1, 100005)
go

create proc SPtest
                @a int = 4,
                @b int = 1
as
select       * from testTable where a = @a and b = @b

exec SPtest 2, 101
```

Above works well. but I need something like this:

```
declare @a int
set @a = 4

select * 
from testTable 
where a = case @a when 4 then select distinct a from testTable end
```

Comment: `CASE` in SQL Server can only return "atomic" values - you cannot run T-SQL code inside the `CASE` statement. You'll need to read those distinct values from the table and storing them in a variable **before** executing this select with the case in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to cut the cookie, this would seem the most logical;

```
IF @a = 4 THEN
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM testTable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM testTable
  WHERE a = @a and b = @b
END
```

Alternatively you can use an or statement;

```
SELECT *
FROM testTable 
WHERE @a = 4 or (a = @a and b = @b)
```

Good luck (would have commented but I not there yet).

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the try, but what I need is:

Comment: Pressed enter by accident. I need if @a = 3 or @a = 2 to see only 2 rows. If @a = 4 I need to see all 6 records, with out using 'IF'. This is just addition to big query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
create proc SPtest
    @a int = 4,
    @b int = 1
as
if @a = 4
    select distinct a from testTable
else
    select * from testTable where a = @a and b = @b
go
exec SPtest
exec SPtest 3,101
```

Comment: It is easy solution by using 'IF'. I do not want to have huge query twice in SP. I would like to solve the problem using "CASE" expression, like I stated in original question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try this then : select * from testTable where @a = 4 or (a = @a and b = @b)